# Filter by multiple subjects IMAPX

Tags: c#, imap, imapx

Is there any way to filter the messages' downloading by more than one specific subject?

For example, I need to download only the messages which contain "for 10" or "for 11" in their respective subjects.

With one subject it's clear:

```
folderSearchMessages.Messages.Download("SUBJECT for 10", messageFetchMode, numMessages)
```

By the way, where could I look for deeper documentation? Rather than the official page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an IMAPX user, but if it's free form text in the search string, you can just use the IMAP search language, detailed in [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) §[6.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4).  If your server supports search correctly (there are a lot that don't), you can use an OR term:

```
folderSearchMessages.Messages.Download("OR (SUBJECT \"for 10\") (SUBJECT \"for 11\")", messageFetchMode, numMessages)
```

Note that you should also quote your strings.